# Default value based on other field

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Is there a way to have the following:

```python
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class ExampleCls:
    category: str
    subcategory: str = f"{category} level 2"
```

1. `ExampleCls(category="hi")`

   - works with `field(init=False)` and returns `ExampleCls(category="hi", subcategory=f"{category} level 2")`
2. `ExampleCls(category="hi", subcategory="greetings")`

   - here I expect `ExampleCls(category="hi", subcategory="greetings")`
   - with `field(init=False)`, I will get an error: `got an unexpected keyword argument 'subcategory'`

the `field(default_factory)` does not accept arguments from the other fields

Comment: [_"Among other uses, \[`__post_init__`\] allows for initializing field values that depend on one or more other fields."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing)

Comment: the solution is     `def __post_init__(self):
        self.log_type = self.log_type if self.log_type else f"{self.category}_geo_exception" `

Comment: setting `init=False` is what got me into the wrong direction to begin with

Comment: You could use `subcategory: Optional[str]`, then have `__post_init__` replace `None` with the `category`-dependent string. I'm not a big fan of that, since the *field* really should have type `str`; only the `__init__` parameter should have type `Optiona[str]`. Right now, I think the "right" approach is to have `subcategory: str = field(init=false)` and `subcategory_: InitVar[Optional[str]`, then use `subcategory_` in `__post_init__` to define `subcategory.

Comment: (I've been mulling over to propose that  `dataclasses` could allow a field and an `InitVar` to share a name, something like `subcategory: str = field(..., init_var_type=Optional[str])`.)

Comment: problem is with `fields(init=False)` that it doesn't allow to pass any subcategory field from the outside. Which I want. Therefore I am currently initialising `subcategory: str = ""` and redefine the value in `__post_init__`. That is also the reason why I would like to reopen this question. The linked content doesn't help